# My Edit PHP is not updating the XML file. Anything wrong with it?

Tags: php, xml

*the code for my edit.php is not working and i dont know why and not updating the product in my xml file, anything wrong with it?* thank you!

```
<?php
$products = simplexml_load_file('product.xml');

if(isset($_POST['UPDATE'])) {

    foreach($products->product as $product){
        if($product->id==$_POST['id']){
            $product->category = $_POST['category'];
            $product->name = $_POST['name'];
            $product->desc = $_POST['desc'];
            $product->price = $_POST['price'];
            $product->quan = $_POST['quan'];
            $product->pic = $_POST['pic'];
            break;
        }
    }
    file_put_contents('product.xml', $products->asXML());
    header('location:index.php');
}


foreach($products->product as $product){
    if($product->id==$_GET['id']){
        $id = $product->id;
        $category = $product->category;
        $name = $product->name;
        $desc = $product->desc;
        $price = $product->price;
        $quan = $product->quan;
        $pic = $product->pic;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a match at `$product->id==$_POST['id']`?

Comment: oh my bad, i try to edit it if($product['id']==$_POST['id']) and it works. thanks!

Comment: @Domingo please submit your solution as an answer to this question, and mark it as correct. This way, your question is marked as resolved in the network.